Supabase db set up Warning: Local config differs from linked project. Try updating supabase/config.toml
I am following https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/subscription-starter and deployed using the Vercel button (Nextjs app).
I have 2 questions:
1) when running pnpm supabase:link I get Warning: Local config differs from linked project. Try updating supabase/config.toml
Full log:
pnpm supabase:link

> @ supabase:link /Repos/subscription-starter
> npx supabase link

Selected project: mjbtktcdhxsrshk
Enter your database password (or leave blank to skip):
Connecting to remote database...
Finished supabase link.
Warning: Local config differs from linked project. Try updating supabase/config.toml
[api]
enabled = true
port = 54321
schemas = ["public", "graphql_public"]
extra_search_path = ["public", "extensions"]
max_rows = 1000


2) When running: pnpm supabase:pull I get
Setting up initial schema....
v1.6.8: Pulling from supabase/storage-api
a258b2a6b59a: Pull complete
...
Digest: sha256:8b...
Status: Downloaded newer image for public.ecr.aws/supabase/storage-api:v1.6.8
v2.156.0: Pulling from supabase/gotrue
690e87867337: Pull complete
...
Digest: sha256:45...
Status: Downloaded newer image for public.ecr.aws/supabase/gotrue:v2.156.0
Applying migration 20230530034630_init.sql...
3.0.1663481299: Pulling from supabase/migra
c30352492317: Pull complete
...
Digest: sha256:56
Status: Downloaded newer image for public.ecr.aws/supabase/migra:3.0.16634
No schema changes found
The auth and storage schemas are excluded. Run supabase db pull --schema auth,storage again to diff them.
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

I tried to run supabase db pull --schema auth,storage which caused a bunch of issues. This is my second attempt so not sure exactly the issue.
Do I follow the instructions and run supabase db pull --schema auth,storage or move to the next instructions:
pnpm supabase:generate-seed
pnpm supabase:reset

I checked the "Add seed data" when creating the project but I don't see any rows in any of the tables (customers, prices, products, subscriptions, users)
